# Netlogo: How to make a turtle move towards an unique patch target?

Tags: netlogo

I have turtles (patients), and they can only use only one bed each (white patch). Since patients are randomly generated in a waiting room (green patches), sometimes two or more of them get at the same distance and therefore they find the same patch as its target. I tried to add an attribute to the patch with the purpose of assigning that particular bed to a specific patient. The idea is something like this (please indulge on the ugly code, I'm learning :P):

```
globals [
  waitxmax
  waitxmin
  waitymax
  waitymin
  box
]

breed [ patients patient ]
patients-own [ target ]
patches-own [ assigned ]

to setup-wait-room
  set waitxmax -15
  set waitxmin 15
  set waitymax 11
  set waitymin 15
  ask patches with [
    pxcor >= waitxmax and
    pxcor <= waitxmin and
    pycor >= waitymax and
    pycor <= waitymin
  ] [ set pcolor green ]
end

to setup-beds

  let cmy 7
  let cmx 15
  let dst 3
  let nbox 7

  ask patch cmx cmy [ set pcolor white ]
   
  let i 1
  while [ i < nbox ] [ 
    ask patch (cmx - dst) cmy [ set pcolor white ]
    
    set i i + 1
    set cmx cmx - dst
  ]
  ask patches with [ pcolor = white ] [ set assigned false ]
  
  set box patches with [ pcolor = white ]
end

to setup-patients
  create-patients start-patients [ 
    set shape "person" 
    set target nobody
    move-to one-of patches with [ pcolor = green ] ]
end

to setup [
  clear-all
  setup-wait-room
  setup-beds
  reset-ticks
]

to go
  ask patients [ go-to-bed ]
  tick
end

to go-to-bed
  let _p box with [ self != [ patch-here ] of myself ]

  if target = nobody [
    set target min-one-of _p [ distance myself ]
    ask target [ set assigned myself ]
  ] 
  
  ;;; FIXME
  if ([ assigned ] of target) != self [ show "not true" ]

  if target != nobody [
    face target
    fd 1 
  ]

end
```

When I print the two sides of the comparison below FIXME, from the command center I actually get the expected result. For example: both patient 0 and patient 1 have the same `target` (patch -3 7), but that patch is `assigned` to (patient 0). I would have expected that comparison to force patient 1 to get a new target since the bed doesn't have his name (I haven't written that code yet), but it always evaluates to true. This is more notorious as more patients I add over available beds (if no beds available, they should wait as soon as one gets free).

When inspecting trough the interface I also see that the patch -3 7 says (patient 0), so I don't know what's happening. Command center example:

```
observer> show [ assigned ] of patch -3 7
observer: (patient 0)
observer> if ([ assigned ] of patch -3 7) = [self] of patient 0  [ show "true" ]
observer: "true"
observer> if ([ assigned ] of patch -3 7) = [self] of patient 1  [ show "true" ]
;;;; SETUP AND GO
(patient 0): (patch -3 7)
(patient 0): (patient 0)
(patient 0): "true"
(patient 2): (patch 12 7)
(patient 2): (patient 2)
(patient 2): "true"
(patient 1): (patch -3 7)
(patient 1): (patient 1)
(patient 1): "true"
```

Maybe I'm just overthinking this and there are is a simpler way to assign a bed to a patient and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a chunk or two missing from your code above (I can't copy-paste and run it), so please have a look at the option below.

This version works by having a single place to store the 'claimed' beds- in the turtle variable. Since the turtle variables can be queried as a list using `of`, a bed-less turtle can check if there are any beds that are not already present in that list and, if so, claim one.

```
turtles-own [ owned-bed ]

to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 5 patches [
    set pcolor green
  ]
  crt 10 [
    set owned-bed nobody
    claim-unclaimed-bed
    if owned-bed != nobody [
      print word "I own the bed " owned-bed
    ]    
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to claim-unclaimed-bed
  ; If I have no bed
  if owned-bed = nobody [
    ; Pull the current owned beds for comparison
    let all-owned-beds [owned-bed] of turtles
    
    ; Pull those beds that are green AND are not found in 'all-owned-beds'
    let available-beds patches with [ 
      pcolor = green and not member? self all-owned-beds    
    ]
    
    ; If there are any beds available, claim one
    ifelse any? available-beds [
      set owned-bed one-of available-beds
    ] [
      ; If there are none available, print so
      print "There are no available beds."
    ]
  ]  
end
```

**Edit:** Forgot the actual question title- to actually move to their `owned-bed` (if they have one) in the example above, they simply `face` it and move how you like- for example:

```
to go
  ask turtles with [ owned-bed != nobody ] [
    ifelse distance owned-bed > 1 [
      face owned-bed
      fd 1
    ] [
      move-to owned-bed
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

**Edit: added complexity**

Ok, for an added element of `severity`, you will likely want to avoid using multiple `with [ ... = x` statements, and instead to use a primitive called `min-one-of` which returns the agent with the minimum value of some reporter. Then, you want to tell NetLogo to keep asking the next most severe and the next most severe, etc. One way to do this is with a `while` loop, which basically says "While this condition is met, continue evaluating the following code." **Be careful** with `while` loops- if you forget to write your code such that eventually the condition is no longer `true`, the `while` loop will just continue running until you will eventually Tools > Halt your model (or, as has happened to me with a large model, NetLogo crashes).

I've reworked the code (much of what was above is unchanged) to include such a `while` loop. Note as well that, since the model needs to check which beds are available multiple times, I've made that code into a `to-report` chunk to condense / simplify.

```
turtles-own [ owned-bed severity ]

to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 5 patches [
    set pcolor green
  ]
  crt 10 [
    set owned-bed nobody
    set severity random-float 10
  ]
  let current-available-beds report-available-beds
  
  while [any? current-available-beds] [
    ; From the turtles with no bed, ask the one with the lowest severity number to 
    ; claim an unclaimed bed. Then, reset the current-available-beds
    ask min-one-of ( turtles with [owned-bed = nobody] ) [ severity ]  [
      claim-unclaimed-bed
      if owned-bed != nobody [
        show ( word "I have a severity of " severity " so I am claiming the bed " owned-bed )
      ]
    ]
    set current-available-beds report-available-beds
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to-report report-available-beds 
  let all-owned-beds [owned-bed] of turtles
  report patches with [
      pcolor = green and not member? self all-owned-beds
  ]
end

to claim-unclaimed-bed
  ; If I have no bed
  if owned-bed = nobody [
    let available-beds report-available-beds

    ; If there are any beds available, claim one
    ifelse any? available-beds [
      set owned-bed one-of available-beds
    ] [
      ; If there are none available, print so
      print "There are no available beds."
    ]
  ]
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, well... I actually was overthinking it. I pasted the code so yeah, maybe I missed something. I'll test it tomorrow probably and I'll give my feedback :)

Comment: It's working perfectly! I had to make some few minor adjustments, but the answer is perfect!. I believe the `ifelse distance ...` should be `< 1` and not `> 1`. Also, I dunno why patients are teleporting instead moving (they arrive on one tick), other breeds move normally with `face target fd 1`. I also tried to remove the logic (distance) there in case `move-to` was being evaluated, but it doesn't. Second thing, is that patients keep moving... maybe I can set a variable when `pcolor = white` and ask with that variable set to false? (it seems a bit too much though....)

Comment: Okay, so I got messed up with the logic with that `ifelse`, I forgot to change the order when reverting the sign so my bad. It stills jump around though, I did about setting a variable like (in go): `ask patients with [ rdy? = false ] [ go-to-bed ]` and while it stops moving it doesn't go necessary into the center. My guessing is that `pcolor = white` happens as soon as the turtle enters the patch. Creating a variable only for this purpose seems overkill.

Comment: Remember that `move-to` is a teleporting command.  Also, since you are doing `face` and then `jump 1` or `Fd 1` at various angles, the turtle’s center may be anywhere inside the patch. If you want them centered, have them make their coordinates the same as the patch, like, `setxy pxcor pycor` when they arrive in the target patch

Comment: I feel like turtles interrogating the other turtles to find a free bed is less… agent-based-ish, versus having a “hospital” agent that manages the bed availability and assignments, or a “bed sign up” sheet that patients update and other patients consult… it’s a semantic twiddle, but there you are.

Comment: Hmm, I don't follow (but I understand I might be getting this wrong). There's only one turtle (patient). I need to use the "beds", because that's variable when you model an emergency department, you could have a lot of physicians, but if you have only one bed, there's a bottleneck.

Comment: @PabloOlmosdeAguileraC. - Did you try running the code that I supplied *as-is*? The movement model provided does stop turtles from moving to a bed if it is already claimed (ie- `ifelse distance ...` should be left as is (> 1), because you want them to move forward 1 only if there is at least that much distance to move.,

Comment: @LukeC yep, it worked perfectly :). I made some minor adjustments but it helped me to understand how to "think" in a more _Netlogy_ way. I marked the answer as accepted :)

Comment: @PabloOlmosdeAguileraC. - Ah ok, glad it was working and that it served to get you pointed in the right direction! Cheers

Comment: @LukeC I just found something, but I don't think is actually a new question, so I ask you first... I added a new attribute for patients (`severity`), the beds should be assigned in order of severity (`4` before `5`) for example, for now it seems to work do something like `... with [ severity = 4 ] [ claim....]` and on the next line `... with [ severity = 5 ] [claim...]`. Since now is assigning based on the distance, I though changing to `[ severity ] of patients` should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @PabloOlmosdeAguileraC. -  Since it builds pretty simply onto the existing code I've provided an option above that may get at what you're after.  However, if you do have further / more complexities than I address above I'd suggest making a new one so that A) more people see the question in case they have different insights and B) so that future users with similar questions would be more likely to find the specific issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LukeC . I was somewhat close, but nevertheless the logic is a lot harder and not immediately obvious (I doubt I could have arrived by myself). Could it be because I'm using patches? I don't know if it's a good idea to turn beds into turtles (I mean, it's hard to see them as turtles as agents), but bed assignment is a very important task when managing ERs so I really don't know if this is actually the best way.

Comment: @PabloOlmosdeAguileraC. - It's definitely a more complex solution, and certainly is only one way of doing things! I think your choice to use patches for beds is a good one from a both a NetLogo sense (patches are stationary agents that occupy space: the entirety of their pcoordinates, discrete values, while turtles do not: they really only 'exist' at their exact xy coordinate, which are continuous values which can lead to extra steps when checking if turtles are interacting / overlapping) and from a simple 'understanding' standpoint- it looks right for the user.